# How precise it the Android Alarm Manager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I know the android alarm manager uses inexact times but I have two questions about it.

1) How granular is the timing?  It seems like 30 seconds.

2) Can it ever fire early by a few seconds?

We think we are seeing a bug in our code stemming from scheduling a time and then comparing that time with a new GregorianCalendar in the alarm-fired intent.  But this only happens very infrequently.

Comment: What are you using as the type? If it is not one of the *_WAKEUP types, the alarm will only be executed when someone/thing wakes up the device.

Comment: It's RTC_Wakeup.  The wakeup works up every phone make we're using for testing but one.

Comment: In that case it looks like a buggy device or firmware. If it's not a super new one, someone has likely ran into it before, you might want to search for device/version specific info.